# RabbitMQ connection.start was never received, likely due to a network timeout .net Web App

Tags: .net, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to get a .Net 4.7.2 web application to connect to a RabbitMQ server running in a (Windows) Docker container (on the same machine as the web app is running in).

**UPDATE: Using a non-Docker version of RabbitMQ does not solve the problem either.  The console connects to the non-Docker RabbitMQ and can publish a message, but the .Net 4.7.2 web app still fails.**

I am using the RabbitMQ.Client 6.2.4 (VMWare) with the following connection code:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
Uri uri = new Uri("amqp://dan:dan@localhost:5672/");
connectionFactory.Uri = uri;
var theConnection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
```

(Note I have also tried with the same results:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 5672, VirtualHost = "/", UserName = "dan", Password = "dan" };
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
)
```

User *dan* exists as an administrator and has rights to the virtual host.

I am receiving the following error:

```
{"None of the specified endpoints were reachable"}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146232800
HelpLink: null
InnerException: {"connection.start was never received, likely due to a network timeout"}
Message: "None of the specified endpoints were reachable"
Source: "RabbitMQ.Client"
StackTrace: "   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)\r\n   at XXXX.Common.BackgroundSubmit.SubmitBackgroundProcess.<>c.<SubmitJob>b__0_0(String connectionURI) in C:\\XXXX.Common\\BackgroundSubmit\\BackgroundSubmitProcess.cs:line 71"
TargetSite: {RabbitMQ.Client.IConnection CreateConnection(RabbitMQ.Client.IEndpointResolver, System.String)}
```

The RabbitMQ log reports this activity:

```
2022-05-18 02:18:59.346295+00:00 [info] <0.1164.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1164.0> (172.19.0.1:55538 -> 172.19.0.2:5672)
2022-05-18 02:18:59.443173+00:00 [warning] <0.1164.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1164.0> (172.19.0.1:55538 -> 172.19.0.2:5672):
2022-05-18 02:18:59.443173+00:00 [warning] <0.1164.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

I created a small console application and that application works fine - it can connect (and subsequently produce a message to a queue).  This console application is .NET 6.0.

I have tried using the actual IP address of my machine as well as 127.0.0.1 and the console connects but the web app does not.

I looked at several tickets and thought maybe this was a good lead:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68011963/factory-createconnection-generates-a-none-of-the-specified-endpoints-were-reac
```

this said make sure that System.Threading.Tasks.Extension, System.Threading.Channels and System.Memory are all the same versions in all referenced projects, and they are.

Also tried using *rabbitmq_localdev* as the rabbit host name in the URI.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

D

Here is the docker-compose .yaml if it helps:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
      # Expose 15672 for the management console, localhost:15672, guest/guest
      # Expose 5672 for the qmpq port
      
      # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747469/how-to-add-initial-users-when-starting-a-rabbitmq-docker-container
    hostname: rabbitmq_localdev
    volumes:
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
        - rabbitmq_go_net

networks:
  rabbitmq_go_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those landing here in the future, I was able to resolve this.

My solution had multiple projects.   The MVC project that had the RabbitMQ connectivity work in it had RabbitMQ.Client as a NuGet package, but the other project did not.   I added RabbitMQ.Client to the other project via NuGet and it solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had the same issue. We have a local nuget that contains the RabbitMQ.Client nuget, so just the local nuget was used and not the RabbitMQ.client nuget. This worked fine with a remotely deployed instance of RabbitMQ but to get it to work with a docker container running locally I had to install the RabbitMQ.client nuget as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'll rephrase the accepted answer.

If you have a `RabbitMQ` client in the **library project**, add the reference of the `RabbitMQ.Client` Nuget package **also to the root of the main project** (MVC project, Job, WCF service, e.t.c). This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a WebApi 4.7.2 application. After spending a lot of hours trying to solve it, what worked for me was downgrading the 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe' package from version 6.0.0 to 4.5.3.